# HTML Text Input * "value"; display in different text input

Tags: javascript, html, input

I've been looking for an answer to this issue but cannot find one. I'm attempting to input a number into a html input tag with the type being 'text'. I then need that value that's placed into that input multiplied by 2 and the answer displayed into another input.

My table looks like this. This is then repeated multiple times and closed with the appropriate table tag.

```
<table class="left-table" style="width:50%">

        <th><u>Expense</u></th>
        <th><u>Weekly</u></th>
        <th><u>Fortnightly</u></th>
        <th><u>Yearly</u></th>

        <tr>
            <td class="options">
                <select class="expense-option">
                    <option>- Select Option -</option>
                    <option>Car Insurance</option>
                    <option>Car Loan</option>
                    <option>Car Park</option>
                    <option>Car Registration</option>
                    <option>Car Servicing</option>
                    <option>Clothes</option>
                    <option>Credit Card</option>
                    <option>Dining Out</option>
                    <option>Donation</option>
                    <option>Entertainment</option>
                    <option>Groceries</option>
                    <option>Health Insurance</option>
                    <option>Internet</option>
                    <option>Mobile Phone</option>
                    <option>Petrol</option>
                    <option>Rent / Mortgage</option>
                    <option>Spending / Pocket Money</option>
                    <option>Sport</option>
                    <option>Utilities</option>
                </select>
            </td>

            <td><input class="amount" id="input10" type="text" placeholder="Weekly $"></td>
            <td><input class="amount" id="output10" type="text" placeholder="Fortnightly $" readonly></td>
            <td><input class="amount" id="output20" type="text" placeholder="Yearly $" readonly></td>  

        </tr>
```

My JS is like this:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#input10").keyup(function(){
 var input1 = parseInt($("#input10").val());
 if(!isNaN(input1)){
     $("#output10").val(input1 * 2);
 }
 else{
     $("#output10").val("");
     alert("Please enter a valid number");
 }
});
</script>
```

But still nothing works.

Comment: look at my answer @Vucko - as well as the quotes making the 2 a string - there is a typo in the <td> structure in the input line. With these errors fixed the code works

Comment: you need to fiund a better way of getting the values if you have multiple inputs - doing it this way will require the above function for every text input (#input 10,#input11, #input12 ...etc As I showed in the page below - the code is itself fine and produces the correct answer - so look to the rest of your page for the error.

Comment: Will have a good look. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#input1").keyup(function(){
 var input1 = parseInt($("#input1").val());
 if(!isNaN(input1)){
     $("#output1").val(input1 * '2');
 }
 else{
     $("#output1").val("");
     alert("Please enter a valid number");
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td><input class="amount" id="input1" type="text" placeholder="Weekly $"></td>
    <td><input class="amount" id="output1" type="text" placeholder="Fortnightly $" readonly></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

```js
$("#input1").keyup(function(){
 var input1 = parseInt($("#input1").val());
 if(!isNaN(input1)){
     $("#output1").val(input1 * '2');
 }
 else{
     $("#output1").val("");
     alert("Please enter a valid number");
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr>
    <td><input class="amount" id="input1" type="text" placeholder="Weekly $"></td>
    <td><input class="amount" id="output1" type="text" placeholder="Fortnightly $" readonly></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

you have a typo in the first line (also assuming you have a table structure of this :

```
<td><input class="amount" id="input1" type="text" placeholder="Weekly $"></td>
<td><input class="amount" id="output1" type="text" placeholder="Fortnightly $" readonly></td>
```

remove the ' characters around the 2 in the line:

```
$("#output1").val(input1 * '2');
```

this makes it a string
you need (in order to keep it a number that can be used for the calculation:

```
$("#output1").val(input1 * 2);
```

The corrected working code is (table structure added):

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input class="amount" id="input1" type="text" placeholder="Weekly $"></td>
            <td><input class="amount" id="output1" type="text" placeholder="Fortnightly $" readonly></td>
        </tr>
    </table>


<script>
$("#input1").keyup(function(){
 var input1 = parseInt($("#input1").val());
 if(!isNaN(input1)){
     $("#output1").val(input1 * 2);
 }
 else{
     $("#output1").val("");
     alert("Please enter a valid number");
 }
});
</script>
```

Comment: check my edit - you have a typo in the input line regarding the td's

Comment: I just popped this code minus the td's into a page that I am working on at the moment and it works - typing a number into the inputbox leads to that number * 2 being displayed in the second box

Comment: So you think it could be the TD's? My paste of the original HTML was a copy and paste job. I accidentally pasted it incorrectly. It is the way you have suggested it in your answer. Could it be that I have multiple TR's of this same input, all with the same ID's? For example:

    <td><input class="amount" id="input1" type="text" placeholder="Weekly $"></td>
<td><input class="amount" id="output1" type="text" placeholder="Fortnightly $" readonly></td>

This is repeated many times to get the desired table I need.

Comment: well it worked in my page as individual inputs with no td's, just make sure that all ID's are unique and you should have no probs

Comment: I'll try changing the ID's of the first 2 to see if that changes. If it does then would I need to have a script for every single ID change to get the desired result for my table?

Comment: I've even changed my ID's to see if that was causing an issue since I have many TR's with the same TD. But this hasn't worked either.

Comment: yes - if you have more thabn 1 (id="input1") forexample - you absolutely need to change that. Id's can only be used once. Then you will need to tweak your script to account for that - perhaps you could use the $(this) in context and do the calculation then amend the next input to the one that was used for the text entry.

Comment: check the snippet in my answer - the code works.... if you have jQuery loaded into the page....if you are not loading jQuery, then you can not use the $('#.... nomenclature.

Comment: I've added the jQuery link as a script from Google.

Comment: If you then add multiple TR / TD with the same information does it still work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have parsed the string to int

```
var input1 = parseInt($("#input1").val());
```

But in appending the value , you are trying to multiple with string 2 as it is enclosed inside '' . So solution of this is very simple, u need to multiple with int value .ie. 2 only.

```
var result = input1 * 2 ;
$("#output1").val(result);
```